# Try-except with if conditions?

Tags: python, if-statement, try-except

I have created if-else statements within my functions to check if certain conditions are met. However, I need to convert it try-except statement since the app I am working on is set up so that when a condition is met, it creates log info statements and when it is not met it creates log error statements. Currently my code looks like:

```
if (conditon1 == 1):
    print('Everything is good')
else:
    orig_diff = list(set(sheetnames).difference(file.sheet_names))
    new_diff = list(set(file.sheet_names).difference(sheetnames))
    if len(orig_diff) != 0:
        print("{} cond1 not met".format(','.join(orig_diff)))
    if len(new_diff) != 0:
        print("{} cond2 not met".format(','.join(new_diff)))
```

I want it to be so that if the if-condition is met then it will print the info statement. But if it is not met, then the else statements will be executed. Something like:

```
try:
   return bool(condition1 == 1)
   print('Everything is good')
except:
   orig_diff = list(set(sheetnames).difference(file.sheet_names))
        new_diff = list(set(file.sheet_names).difference(sheetnames))
        if len(orig_diff) != 0:
            print("{} cond1 not met".format(','.join(orig_diff)))
        if len(new_diff) != 0:
            print("{} cond2 not met".format(','.join(new_diff)))
```

But, I can't seem to get this to work and even when the condition is not met it returns 'Everything is good'.

Comment: bool will return True or False not raise an Error condition so the except code will never be used.

Comment: You have working code but you want to turn it into `try ... except`, because... why? If you can explain how this code is *exceptional*, then a solution to the "what exception should I throw" problem will present itself during that explanation. But if you're doing this just because you want to use `try` rather than `if` then that's a poor reason to do anything.

Comment: As I explained in the post, I am working on an already developed framework and I need to alter my code so it fits the framework.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be a good way of doing it - if cond1 equals 1, it'll go down the *happy path*, the `else` block. If it doesn't (the `assert`ion fails, so the condition isn't met), it does what you wanted it to - prints an error message.

```
try:
   assert(condition1 == 1)
except AssertionError:
   orig_diff = list(set(sheetnames).difference(file.sheet_names))
        new_diff = list(set(file.sheet_names).difference(sheetnames))
        if len(orig_diff) != 0:
            print("{} cond1 not met".format(','.join(orig_diff)))
        if len(new_diff) != 0:
            print("{} cond2 not met".format(','.join(new_diff)))
else:
    print("Everything's fine!")
```

Comment: To find out more about assertions, see [this docs page](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement). Mostly - if an assertion fails (gets a falsey value) it raises an `AssertionError`.

Comment: Adding in assert worked. Thank you, I didn't know that assert statements could do this. Thanks for further reading info!

Comment: With that being said, an if statement may be more readable in the future - I'm not sure why the first example you posted didn't work.

Comment: It worked, I just have to get into a try except so it fits the framework of the already developed code being used for the rest of the app.